# ColdFusion 8 Most efficient use of variable

Tags: coldfusion, resources, coldfusion-8

I am parsing a file and need to do something based on the file's content. Which is most efficient, would use less resources or is best practice.

1. Accessing the file item within the if statement directly
2. Assigning that items value to a variable.

Here is an example of each:

(1)

```
<cfset file = XmlParse(file.filecontent)>
<cfif file.item1.xmltext neq "" & file.item2.xmltext neq "">
```

or

(2)

```
<cfset file = XmlParse(file.filecontent)>
<cfset item1 = file.item1.xmltext>
<cfif item1 neq "">
```

Keeping in mind that the same variable maybe accessed a few times throughout the program to test conditions.

Comment: The only way to know is to test...

Comment: I would think the win that you get from code clarity would trump any savings you'd get in micro-optimising for performance here. But it's easy enough to strum up a load test to check, innit?

Comment: I would avoid using `file` as a variable name, given it's already a built-in CF scope

Comment: I would add a scope to the variables if I was concerned about performance.

Comment: Just FYI, `<cfif len(variable)>` is generally more performant than `<cfif variable NEQ "">`

Comment: Be very cautious of micro-optimisation suggestions.